# calling a script from daemon

Tags: python, python-daemon

I am trying to call a script from python-daemon but its not working. this is what i am tying to do, is it correct?

I also want to pass a random argument to that script, currently i have hard coded it

```
import daemon
import time
import subprocess
import os

def interval_monitoring():
    print "Inside interval monitoring"
    while True:
        print "its working"
#         os.system("XYZ.py 5416ce0eac3d94693cf7dbd8") Tried this too but not working
        subprocess.Popen("XYZ.py 5416ce0eac3d94693cf7dbd8", shell=False)
        time.sleep(60)
        print "condition true"




def run():
    print daemon.__file__
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        interval_monitoring()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't make `XYZ.py` executable and added `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the top line, you need to call it via python, rather than directly. So your line would be something like this:

`subprocess.check_output(["python", "XYZ.py", "5416ce0eac3d94693cf7dbd8"])`